# Understanding Magento Block and Block Type

Tags: magento

I just want to understand the meaning of

```
 <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="example/view.phtml">
```

I got many references from Google and understood many things about it but I am still unable to understand the formation of `type="page/html"` how to form a type for my custom module.

Please explain

```
type="A/B"
```

Let me know where this A and B come from?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The `A` is a module's *alias*. In this case `page` is short for `Mage_Page_Block` (it is defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml` if you want to see).

The `B` is the class name relative to the alias, initial letters of each word are capitalised. In this case `html` becomes `Html` and is appended to the resolved alias, so it is **`Mage_Page_Block_Html`**. This is probably found in the file `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html.php` because class names translate directly to locations in Magento.

Were you using a model alias instead of a block alias then `page` would be `Mage_Page_Model` instead. The same thing happens for resource models and helpers too. Your own module will need to define these in it's [config](http://alanstorm.com/magento_config) if it is to have blocks, models and helpers.

Comment: Nice Explaination

Comment: What if it is a rewrited/overrided block, how can I define and use block type then ?

Comment: @VickyDev you don't need to do anything different as the new block will be a descendant of the old block and so is compatible. You can, and should, pretend it doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 158):

For understanding more about magento block types following are some built-in block types which are widely used in layout.

1. `core/template`: This block renders a template defined by its `template` attribute. The majority of blocks defined in the layout are of type or subtype of `core/template`.
2. `page/html`: This is a subtype of `core/template` and defines the root block. All other blocks are child blocks of this block.
3. `page/html_head`: Defines the HTML head section of the page which contains elements for including JavaScript, CSS etc.
4. `page/html_header`: Defines the header part of the page which contains the site logo, top links, etc.
5. `page/template_links`: This block is used to create a list of links. Links visible in the footer and header area use this block type.
6. `core/text_list`: Some blocks like `content`, `left`, `right` etc. are of type `core/text_list`. When these blocks are rendered, all their child blocks are rendered automatically without the need to call the`getChildHtml()` method.
7. `page/html_wrapper`: This block is used to create a wrapper block which renders its child blocks inside an HTML tag set by the action `setHtmlTagName`. The default tag is `<div>` if no element is set.
8. `page/html_breadcrumbs`: This block defines breadcrumbs on the page.
9. `page/html_footer`: Defines footer area of page which contains footer links, copyright message etc.
10. `core/messages`: This block renders error/success/notice messages.
11. `page/switch`: This block can be used for the language or store switcher.

This is a list of only commonly used block types. There are many other block types which are used in advanced theme implementations.

Comment: What about :
{{ block type="cms/block" block_id="terms" }}

Comment: @daslicht  Already mentioned in answer that :This is a list of only commonly used block types. There are many other block types which are used in advanced theme implementations.

Comment: Thanks. Was really helpful.

Answer (score 8):

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="example/view.phtml">
```

page is a FrontendName defined in `etc/config.xml` file
html is a block class name

more details:

in this line `type(type="page/html")` define block class name related to your `template(template="example/view.phtml">)` and name is the unique for each block.

first see folder structure

> app>local>namespace>modulename>etc>config.xml

we set `FrontendName = 'mymodule'`

> app>local>namespace>modulename>**Block**>hello.php

in hello.php you created a function

```
   class namespace_modulename_Block_Data extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
   {
    public function mydata()
        {
            $data = "Block is called";
            return $data;
         }     
}
```

and now come to your layout xml page:

`<block type="mymodule/data" name="xyz" template="example/view.phtml">`
here mydata is frontend name

and now come to your template's

> template/example/view.phtml page

here you can call directly mydata() function

like

```
<div>
<?php echo $this->mydata(); ?>
</div>
```

now you can get your output in browser
"Block is called"

Comment: You named the block hello.php but the name of the block class is 'namespace_modulename_Block_Data' , should'nt it be Hello at the end of the name?

Answer (score 5):

> i don't know about "B" type, but "A" refer to your module name tag in config.xml
>   example in config.xml:
>
> ```
> <A><!-- script --></A>
> ```

No, you're not wrong. But the `"<!-- script -->"` may be confusing. Let's clarify: as the above answers stated, this is an alias, which consisted of two parts, the first part ("A") itself is the alias you define to your module's classes in your module's `config.xml`, the second is a path relative to the node's value. These together ("A" + capitalized "B") will be translated to a class name, using the first part (the "A" node's value) exactly as you define it (watch for upper/lowercase if you don't want hours of suffering) and the second part is capitalized after each underscore. So, start with the A/B example with a block and this config:

```
<config>
  ...
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <A>Vendor_Module_Block</A>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  ...
</config>
```

In runtime `A/B` would resolved by the Magento config to `Vendor_Module_Block_B` which would then included by the autoload from the following path: `public/app/local/Vendor/Module/Block/B.php`. To get a better understanding I advise you to take a look at the `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName()`, `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getModelInstance()` and `Varien_Autoload::autoload()`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about "B" type, but "A" refer to your module name tag in config.xml

An example in the config.xml file:

```
<A><!-- script --></A>
```

nb: i hope i'm not wrong..