# call .phtml file in another .phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed a new extension having a block_featured_products.phtml file under folder inchoo/featuredproducts . I want to call this file in my index.phtml that is under cms folder.

Here which I tried after google search but not working:

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('inchoo/featuredproducts/block_featured_products.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `inchoo/featuredproducts/block_featured_products.phtml` exists, are you able to output anything from said file (clear contents and throw in some [Lorem Ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/feed), for example) when it's called?

Personally, I would recommend using XML (`cms.xml`, `page.xml`, or simply `local.xml`) to define your block and its template, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
    <reference name="content">
      <block name="block_featured_products" template="inchoo/featuredproducts/block_featured_products.phtml" type="core/template" />
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

Then, in your template file(s), use `getChildHtml` to call your block, like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('block_featured_products'); ?>
```

**Resources:**

- [Understanding Magento Block and Block Type](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6633307/understanding-magento-block-and-block-type)

Answer (score 0):

**To Display .phtml file in another .phtml file. you can use:**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('path after template dir/filename.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('featuredproducts/listing')->setTemplate('inchoo/featuredproducts/block_featured_products.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Go to the extension etc folder where you find config.xml file and in the config.xml file you find  tag understanding the block tag you can write your own block tag or you can use that block tag, normally when creating an extension using block tag we move to block folder and in using slash we use to give file name if i want to access Listing .php then i use /listing that's how its work

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you edit it to explain why this code works.

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: Go to the extension etc folder where you find config.xml file and in the config.xml file you find <block> tag understanding the block tag you can write your own block tag or you can use that block tag, normally when creating an extension using block tag we move to block folder and in using slash we use to give file name if i want to access Listing .php then i use /listing that's how its work

Comment: now you able to understand what i mean to say @Blackwood

Comment: My suggestion was to you edit your answer to include the explanation (rather than add a comment). That is not so that I will understand, but so that anyone reading your answer in the future will be able to find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

1) For calling a core template file in .phtml file

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('templateFolder/yourtemplate.phtml')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

2) For calling a core template file in CMS page

```
{{block type="core/template" template="templateFolder/your_template.phtml"}}
```